# Definite integral involving combination of power, exponential, and confluent hypergeometric function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

Is there a solution, or an approximation, to the following integral?

$$\int_0^P e^{\delta x}x^{n-m}\, _1F_1\Big(n;m;\sigma (P-x)\Big)dx $$

where m, n, $\delta$ and $\sigma$ are real. I can redefine $\delta$ and $\sigma$ to $-\delta$ and $-\sigma$ if it makes the derivation easier.

Comment: You can rephrase it as a convolution and do a multiplication in the Laplace transform space.  The inversion will probably take some effort though.

Comment: Since you indicated that an approximation would do there are two ways that yield series.  One is using the incomplete gamma function.  Which, while not favored by mathematicians,  has coefficients that have an easy recursion formula and so should run fast.  The other is to recognize an Appell sequence and write up the series as an infinite sum in x^p with finite series as the multipliers.  If you're interested I will submit these.  Both have closed forms for coefficients but I don't know how to close the overall sum.

Comment: A Laplace transformation sounds like a good idea to start with. I would prefer a solution but working out an approximation could help me figure out the actual solution. I am very interested in what you have to offer rrogers.